# Clipping a vector line shapefile in QGIS based on a raster shapefile?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, clip

I have a vector line 'straten' shapefile which I want to have cliped based on raster shapefile "Luchtfoto 2016". Because some streets are running out of tmy raster, I want to have the vector cliped.

[image]

I know this in Arcgis but not in QGIS. How can I do this? 
Yes I can easily deleted the shapes that run out of the raster, but some lines are just too long and only consists of one segment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would probably do the following:

1. Use the **Raster Calculator** on your *"Luchtfoto2016"*:

   ```
   Raster > Raster Calculator...
   ```

   And use the following expression:

   ```
   Luchtfoto2016@1 = 0
   ```

   This will save a new raster with all cells equal to zero (this should dramatically speed up the next step).

---

2. Use the **Polygonize** tool on your newly saved raster to convert it to a polygon:

   ```
   Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector)
   ```

---

3. Use the **Clip** tool on your line layer with the new polygon layer.

   ```
   Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clip
   ```